# how to GET data into views.py then POST to database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am newbie on python and Django, just learn and follow online tutorial. But now iam facing a issues that i cannot find or i dont know what keyword should i put on the search to find the solution.

i have this on my views.py

```
salary = 212

class EmployeeCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('id','name', 'salary')
    model = models.Employee

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.name = salary
        self.object.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

my question is, how make 'salary' reference to database?...

example 
I have atendance table :

```
id | employe_id | working_days |
--------------------------------
1  |        123 |           21 |
```

i want 'salary' reference to atendance table, so i can make

```
salary = working_days * 50
```

thank you for helping newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import your atendance model in `views.py`.

```
 atendance_obj = models.atendance.objects.get(employe_id=self.object.id)
 working_days = atendance_obj.working_days
 salary = working_days * 50
```

Comment: What is model name for your table `atendance`?

Comment: `class atendance(models.Model):` this is from my models.py

Comment: did you import that in your `views.py`?

Comment: `from . import models` yes, i do like this.

Comment: Then use `models.atendance.objects.get(employe_id=self.object.id)`. Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Give traceback or atleast copy paste the line where this error is coming from?